# How to change the colours of the background of the screen in kivy app module of python?

Tags: python, widget, screen, kivy, kivy-language

I have a developed kivy app in python but I have an issue: Sometimes the black background is too dark and I wonder if it's possible that in Kivy the attribute `Screen` has a property that could change to negative colours, I mean, like some mobile phones that you can choose to change all the colours of the mobile to negative, solving the problem of the colours. I'm new about developing with Kivy, so I don't know about the potentiality of Kivy about solving this problem. I've been looking for a few days and I haven't found out anything. If someone knows how to fix this incovenience it would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't know about that(changing it globally), but it'd be a nice feature. Otherwise I guess you'd need to make your own function to change `background_color` of each widget you need to.

Answer (score 5):

You can set background color to a certain value globally by using `Window.clearcolor`:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (.9, .9, .9, 1)
```

You can also set it manually per screen (or pretty much any widget) by drawing on its canvas.

```
<WhiteScreen@Screen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Or change `Window.clearcolor` each time you enter a screen that needs different background, preferably overwriting [`on_pre_enter`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen) method, and setting it back in `on_leave`.

Comment: I get undefined Window object on macos run time any Suggestion ?

Comment: @NikolaLukic You could try importing it later in code.